# Solve_ivp events

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to implement an event in my code so that the ode solver stops when the variable ep becomes greater than one, but I'm not sure how to do it as there is not much literature on the scipy reference guide. Here is my current output and code [Output from the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOijQ.png)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy import integrate 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 6

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)

#Define Parameters.
n = float(input('Enter the value of n: '))


##############################################################
#I.C
H0 = (20.2,)
H_0 = 20.2
dH0 = 0.3       

#Define the potential
def V_func(t, n):
    return t**n
##############################################################
#Range of Phi.
t_span = np.linspace(start = (3*H_0**2 - 2*dH0**2)**(1/n) , stop = 0 , num = 800) 

##############################################################
#Define H-J equation
def f(t, H, n):
    dh = np.sqrt((3/2)*H**2 - (1/2)*V_func(t ,n))
    return dh

##############################################################
#Find H for each value of phi by solving ODE.
def I_end(t, dh, n):
    return dh
I_end.terminal = True
I_end.direction = -1


sol = integrate.solve_ivp(f, (((3*H_0**2 - 2*dH0**2)**(1/n)),0), H0, t_eval = t_span, method = 'Radau' , rtol = 1e-9, events = I_end, args = (n,),)

H1 = sol.y
t = sol.t

H = H1[0,:]

dH = np.sqrt((3/2)*H**2 - (1/2)*V_func(t ,n))
##############################################################
#New
ep = 2*(dH/H)**2    
##############################################################
#Plot epsilon

print(H)

plt.plot(t, dH)

#plt.yscale('log')

plt.title('$\epsilon$ Vs $\phi$ for n = ' +str(n))

plt.xlabel('$\phi$')

plt.ylabel('$\epsilon$')

plt.show()
```

Thanks.